# React Hook Form isSubmitting not being set properly

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a form in which I am displaying a loading indicator when it is submitting.

However, it appears that the `isSubmitting` property seems to be set off and on really quickly and doesn't show the loading indicator at all. I've throttled the network speed to something like "Slow 3G" in Chrome's dev tools and I see my form wait and wait during submission but no loading indicator is shown.

```
const myForm = () => {
    const formMethods = useForm()
    const { formState, handleSubmit } = formMethods
    const { isSubmitting } = formState

    const onSubmit = () => {
        // Submit the form
    }

    return (
        <>
            {isSubmitting && <LoadingIndicator />}
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

            </form>
        </>
    )
}
```

If I add a:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(isSubmitting)
}, [isSubmitting])
```

I see the following printed out almost instantaneously while the form still waits for a low network submission to occur.

```
true
false
```

How do I get React Hook Form to properly show the loading indicator?

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting the form details to API call then you can use `useState` and update it in api call. check e.g. below.

```
    const formMethods = useForm()
    const { formState, handleSubmit } = formMethods
    const { isSubmitting } = formState
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState;

    const onSubmit = () => {
      setIsLoading(true)
      YOUR_API_CALL
        .then((res) => {
          setIsLoading(false)
      })
        .catch((err) => {
          setIsLoading(false)
      })
    }

    return (
        <>
            {isLoading 
              ? <LoadingIndicator /> 
              : (
               <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

               </form>
            )}
        </>
    )
}
```